SVG clipPath not showing
I'm trying to use an SVG over a video as a clipPath. I tried one SVG, which is showing the intended result. However, the other doesn't.
Plus, is there a way to de-couple the video from the svg tag for it to be independent?
Here's my working code:
<section
            id="home"
            style={{
                height: "100svh"
            }}
        >
            <div className="video">
                <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    // viewBox="0 0 300.000000 208.000000"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
                    style={{ position: "absolute" }}
                >
                    <defs>
                        <filter
                            id="prefix__b" width="104.6%" height="107.5%"
                            // x="-2.8%" y="-2.9%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox"
                        >
                            {/* <feOffset dx="-4" dy="4" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"/>
                            <feGaussianBlur
                                in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="5.5"
                            />
                            <feColorMatrix
                                in="shadowBlurOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.3 0"
                            /> */}
                        </filter>
                        <clipPath id="mask">
                            <path
                                d="M0,370.6c-0.5,35,29.5,68,60,82.8c40.8,19.7,82.2,6.8,99.3,1.4c76-23.8,83.3-81.4,130.3-79.9c43.9,1.4,53.2,52.1,102.2,52.5
                                c38.6,0.3,67.2-30.9,79.9-44.6c44.4-48.3,49.5-116.9,33.1-165.5c-6-17.7-11.5-34.1-27.4-45.3c-30.9-22-62.5,2.7-96.2-16.2 c-27.9-15.7-17.7-39-44.8-68c-44.9-47.9-125.5-40.2-155.5-37.3C145.6,53.7,101.3,58,66.5,92c-43.9,42.9-46.3,107.1-46.8,120.2 c-1.7,45.2,14.1,62.2,1.4,103.6C12.1,345.6,0.3,348.8,0,370.6z"
                            />
                            <path
                                d="M373.8,89.9c2.7-4.9,14.3-24.5,37.4-30.2c5.6-1.4,18.5-4.6,30.9,2.2c18.8,10.2,20,33.9,20.2,38.1c0.1,3.2,0.6,21.6-8.6,25.9 c-6.9,3.3-13-4.5-24.5-1.4c-7.4,1.9-7.1,5.7-13.7,7.9c-12.5,4.2-32-3.2-39.6-18.7C371.2,103.7,372.8,94,373.8,89.9z"
                            />
                            <path
                                d="M432.1,133.8c-4.2,1.6-9.3,6-8.6,10.8c0.7,5.5,8.7,9.2,15.1,7.9c6.7-1.4,12.4-8.5,10.8-13.7 C447.7,133.4,438.5,131.3,432.1,133.8z"
                            />
                        </clipPath>
                    </defs>
                </svg>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 814 506">
                    <use fill="#000" filter="url(#prefix__b)" xlinkHref="#prefix__a"/>
                    <foreignObject clipPath="url(#mask)" width="814" height="800">
                        <video
                            autoPlay={true}
                            loop={true}
                            muted={true}
                            width="100%"
                            height="100%"
                            controls
                            style={{ objectFit: "cover" }}
                        >
                            <source src="vids/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                            Your browser does not support the video playback
                        </video>
                    </foreignObject>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </section>

This is the SVG I'm trying to use instead of the working one (this one doesn't work):
<svg
    id="prefix__b"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width={width}
    height={height}
    viewBox="0 0 300.000000 208.000000"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
>
    <defs>
        <mask>
            <clipPath id="cut-video">
                <g
                    transform="translate(0.000000,208.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
                    fill="red" stroke="none"
                >
                    <path
                        d="M513 2046 c-201 -51 -368 -226 -450 -471 -23 -70 -26 -96 -26 -210 0
                        -114 3 -140 26 -210 70 -212 223 -360 427 -411 112 -28 236 -16 405 40 77 26
                        174 52 215 58 69 10 78 10 117 -10 51 -26 79 -72 131 -209 111 -290 301 -489
                        547 -570 68 -22 98 -26 200 -27 131 0 202 14 311 64 253 114 463 380 536 679
                        31 124 30 323 -1 441 -75 282 -280 493 -557 572 -112 32 -305 32 -417 0 -106
                        -30 -142 -50 -279 -152 -172 -130 -259 -155 -364 -106 -59 27 -102 75 -173
                        191 -95 156 -214 261 -356 315 -74 28 -215 36 -292 16z m298 -45 c129 -49 228
                        -136 335 -297 112 -169 171 -214 278 -214 82 0 149 30 271 123 144 109 186
                        133 281 158 102 27 287 30 386 6 269 -66 480 -274 560 -553 32 -110 32 -340 0
                        -456 -52 -192 -146 -352 -284 -484 -99 -95 -194 -155 -316 -197 -78 -28 -99
                        -31 -207 -32 -106 0 -130 3 -210 29 -157 52 -311 172 -414 324 -49 73 -79 133
                        -125 254 -44 115 -95 180 -154 195 -56 14 -147 -1 -287 -47 -221 -73 -302 -83
                        -424 -55 -109 26 -188 71 -268 150 -248 247 -242 661 14 945 151 167 367 225
                        564 151z"
                    />
                </g>
            </clipPath>
        </mask>
    </defs>
</svg>

Thanks in advance...

You could probably use the clippath directly on a video with the CSS property clip-path which supports pointing to SVG paths, which would sort-of decouple.

Can you provide "working" examples, rather than just C&P from your templates?

Please inspect your clip-path. It is actually a compound path describing the a hard-coded stroke - so the clip-path cuts out only a thin area around the basic shape. Besides you probably need to set clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" to get the desired responsive result. Try also https://yoksel.github.io/relative-clip-path/ to test the correct clip-path area
